# How to stop GPS BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, locationmanager, android-gps

I use broadcastreceiver on my gps that check if an user disabled GPS while app working. If the user disabled, then shows a dialog with information that a GPS is requaired.

This is my sample in manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".BroadCastGPS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is my BroadCastGPS class:

```
public class BroadCastGPS extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                if(!gpsStatus.GPS) {

                    Intent pushintent = new Intent(context, gpsStatus.class);
                    pushintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(pushintent);

                }

            } else {

                if(gpsStatus.GPS) {

                    Intent pushintent = new Intent(context, Online.class);
                    pushintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(pushintent);

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

My problem is that, when an user closed this app, after few seconds shows dialog with information, that GPS is requaired. How can I stop broadcast before close app? I try use System.exit(0), kill process but it not works.

This sample is called while close app:

```
PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
ComponentName compName =
        new ComponentName(mContext,
                BroadCastGPS.class);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        compName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never try force closing you Application. Android handles that. If you want to turn off your compenent use [setComponentEnabledSetting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int))

Comment: I updated my question. When I first start, all is great. My Broadcast works. But when I close app and I run second time then a broadcast not works.

Answer (score 0):

Just un register the broadcastreceiver while the user is disabling the gps.

```
 unregisterReceiver(YOUR_BROADCAST);
```